# How to use mahout random forest in real project?

Tags: java, classification, mahout, decision-tree

The list below are some packages related to classifier among mahout-distribution-0.8.

- org.apache.mahout.classifier
- org.apache.mahout.classifier.df
- org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.builder
- org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.data
- org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.data.conditions
- org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce
- org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.inmem
- org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.partial
- org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.node
- org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.ref
- org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.split
- org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools

I guess "df" mentioned above means "decision forest". I am not good at mahout and its source code makes me crazy, so I want to find a mahout decision forest example to see how to use these packages just like the HelloWorldClustering code in Chapter 7 Introduction to clustering Mahout in Action.

I have suffered from this problem for a while. I surf a lot of articles on the Internet but still don't find an effective example yet to tell me how to write the code in real project. Can anyone give me an example with code?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been using Mahout's DecisionForest, and the best resource i've found to help is Mark Needham and Jennifer Smith's example:

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2012/10/27/kaggle-digit-recognizer-mahout-random-forest-attempt/

Take a look at that, the GitHub repository is at the bottom of the page.